# When i am removing my account from stripe in node it gives some err

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I get the error:

> You cannot delete the default external account for your default currency. Please make another external account the default using the `default_for_currency` param, and then delete this one.

err1 StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot delete the default external account for your default currency. Please make another external account the default using the `default_for_currency` param, and then delete this one.
at Function.generate (/var/www/html/SageRider/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:38:16)
at IncomingMessage. (/var/www/html/SageRider/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:175:33)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1199:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
message: 'You cannot delete the default external account for your default currency. Please make another external account the default using the `default_for_currency` param, and then delete this one.',
type: 'invalid_request_error',
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Thu, 25 Jun 2020 19:28:55 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '264',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'request-id': 'req_bXINneBUbmPyo2',
'stripe-account': 'acct_1GwmPSFNjTTd70ro',
'stripe-version': '2019-12-03',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
statusCode: 400,
requestId: 'req_bXINneBUbmPyo2'
},
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
code: undefined,
param: undefined,
detail: undefined,
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Thu, 25 Jun 2020 19:28:55 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',

The code I use is:

```
 stripe.accounts.deleteExternalAccount(
        cryptr.decrypt(data[0].accountId),
        cryptr.decrypt(data[0].bankAccountId),
        function(err, confirmation) {
          if(err) {
            console.log("err1",err)

              callback(err, false)
          }else {
                console.log("confirmation",confirmation)

                callback(false, true)
              }
```

Answer (score 2):

Today, you can not remove the last external account saved on a Custom account in the API. Stripe requires that an account always has a valid bank account for the currency once you've added this.

My guess is that this is the error you are getting right now though you didn't share the exact message. In that case, you need to change your code to stop removing the last external account or replace it by a new external account instead.

Comment: Simply how to remove account from stripe I want to know,As i share the err is exact which it gives me from stripe.Can you share your code for deleteExternalAccount from stripe

Comment: @Harpritsingh You didn't really share the exact error message you get or whether your account has other bank accounts in another currency. You just can not delete the last bank account for each currency, that's not possible. You likely should talk to Stripe's support team instead though https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Okay re-reading the message I misunderstood the error message was the first paragraph so I edited it. But really the issue is you can not do what you are trying to do!